# Why setting data_class doesn't work in Sonata Admin config?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

My question is related to: [How to configure m2m relationship in Sonata Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604150/how-to-configure-m2m-relationship-in-sonata-admin/27604294#27604294)

After configure admin class according to related answer I got:

> The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class
>   Syloc\Bundle\GooglePlacesBundle\Entity\PlaceType. You can avoid this
>   error by setting the "data_class" option to
>   "Syloc\Bundle\GooglePlacesBundle\Entity\PlaceType" or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms an instance of class
>   Syloc\Bundle\GooglePlacesBundle\Entity\PlaceType to scalar, array or
>   an instance of \ArrayAccess.

So I added this property:

```
->add('types', 'collection', array(
            'type'         => 'text',
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'data_class' => 'Syloc\Bundle\GooglePlacesBundle\Entity\PlaceType',
        ));
```

This leads to error:

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class
>   Syloc\Bundle\GooglePlacesBundle\Entity\PlaceType, but is an instance
>   of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection. You can avoid this error
>   by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms an instance of class
>   Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection to an instance of
>   Syloc\Bundle\GooglePlacesBundle\Entity\PlaceType.

Answer (score 2):

I ended with:

```
     ->add('types', 'entity', array(
            'class'         => 'GooglePlacesBundle:PlaceType',
            'property' => 'type',
            'multiple' => true,
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data_class` attribute is not an option on `collection`.  It seems like you might want want your 'type' to be:

```
->add('types', 'collection', array(
    'type'      => '\Syloc\Bundle\GooglePlacesBundle\Entity\PlaceType',
    'allow_add' = true
));
```

Now this is assuming that `PlaceType` is a custom form type you created and not just your entity.

See my answer here if this is what you looking for, for further explanation: [How do I make a form with a bunch of unrelated entities in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514220/how-do-i-make-a-form-with-a-bunch-of-unrelated-entities-in-symfony2/27514883#27514883)

Answer (score 0):

try to use the sonata-type-collection :

```
->add('types', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'by_reference' => true,
                'btn_add' => false,
                'required' => true,
                'label' => false,
                'type_options' => array('delete' => false),
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                ), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
            ))
```